Stability of hemiaminals
How stable are hemiaminals compounds with NH2 and OH groups attached to the same carbon atom? Does the removal of ammonia take place just like water is removed in case when 2 -OH are attached to the same atom?

Quite probably so.

Hemiaminals are less prone to elimination than gem-diols. Often it's water elimination, rather than ammonia.

Hemiaminals compounds with NH2 and OH groups attached to the same carbon atom are usually not stable, because they often dehydrate to produce imines, which then polymerise to produce hexamethylenetetramine. However, hemiaminals with strong electron-withdrawing groups like fluorine on the carbon can be surprisingly stable. The adduct of ammonia and hexafluoroacetone, $\ce{(CF3)2C(OH)NH2}$, is an uncommon stable case. (1)
A similar process is seen in gem-diols (compounds with two hydroxyl groups on the same carbon). Both processes involve the elimination of a molecule with a highly electronegative atom (oxygen or nitrogen) to form a more stable double bond.  However, the eliminated molecule differs in some cases. Gem-diols lose one water(H2O) molecule, forming a carbonyl group (C=O). Hemiaminals often lose water too, but can also lose ammonia.
References:
(1) W. J. Middleton, H. D. Carlson (1970). "Hexafluoroacetone imine". Org. Syntheses. 50: 81–3. doi:10.15227/orgsyn.050.0081 (https://orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV6P0664)

Uh ... where did you get this information? The first paragraph smells a lot like Wikipedia.

Yeah, I shall cite that.

Wikipedia is not a reliable source for citations and, as any other encyclopedia, should never be used as a reference because it isn't the primary source. Chemical formulas should be formatted as such, preferably using mhchem. Finally, a reminder that posting answers written with GPT or with the assistance of any LLM is not permitted — your recent answers are in contrast with the earlier ones and mostly come up as fully/partially generated with "A.I."

@andselisk I understand the first two pointers you made, and I have made the changes to my response. To answer the last pointer you made, I used an LLM to rephrase certain sentences that I was not sure about, in terms of its structure. English is not my first language, and therefore, I sometimes tend to use LLMs to correct grammar, or restructure certain sentences that might sound off.

Also, a guide to chemical formatting: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/faq-how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange. You are expected to use formatting for chemical formulas.
